# Can we count the number of inversions in time $\mathcal{O}(n)$?

Tags: complexity-theory, asymptotics, lower-bounds, permutations

It is possible to find the total number of inversions by $\mathcal{O}(n\log{}n)$ running time (extension of merge-sort algorithm for example).

Is there more asymptotically efficient way to do it? $\mathcal{O}(n)$? 
Or is there any proof that’s not possible?

Comment: Note that "faster than O(...)" is a meaningless phrase.

Comment: Note also that there is lots of room between $\Theta(n \log n)$ and $O(n)$. Are you not interested in, say, an $\Theta(n \log(\log n))$ algorithm?

Comment: I already answered this question once...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are $o(n\log n)$ algorithms in the RAM model. [Dietz](https://urresearch.rochester.edu/fileDownloadForInstitutionalItem.action?itemId=5259&itemFileId=8145) gave an $O(n\log n/\log\log n)$ algorithm in his 1989 paper *Optimal algorithms for list indexing and subset rank*, and [Chan and Pătraşcu](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c390/8c9d0184984cc0cacb562813d5f8afef388c.pdf) gave an $O(n\sqrt{\log n})$ algorithm in their 2010 paper *Counting inversions, offline orthogonal range counting, and related problems*. Chan and Pătraşcu also gave an $O(n)$ algorithm for finding a $1+\epsilon$ approximation, for any $\epsilon>0$.

If you only allow comparisons, then there is an $\Omega(n\log n)$ lower bound, see [this question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/30704/lower-bounds-for-inversion-counting-in-comparison-model) on cstheory.